# Make object float on a displaced plane

Tags: node-editor, displacement, shrinkwrap

I have a plane with a displacement node (that represents an ocean).

[image]

On top of it, I have another plane (that represents a boat). I want to make the boat float on the ocean via a "shrinkwrap modifier":
[image]

But as you can see, the modifier does not take into account the displacement. Any ideas on how to deal with this proble?

Comment: maybe use a Displace modifier instead?

Comment: I am actually using a displacement that is more complicated than a simple z shift. In fact, my displacement is driven by a OSL shader. I don't know how to that with a displacement modifier.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that the Displacement node could be used for another axis than Z